# How to display error message log in page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display an error message if a username does not match the correct password in the database when attempting to log in. I can get the page to work if the user name and password are correct but have no idea as to what is wrong with my code as far as the error message.

```
if ($Password != Password($User_Name))
{
    showForm("Invalid User Name or Password. Please Try Again");
    exit();
}
else {
    include "index.php";
    exit();
}
```

Now, below this code, right before the HTML another programmer wrote the following function:

```
function showForm($formMessage='Invalid User Name And Password. Please Try Again.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try and update your function to display the message to get your code working. Since your are passing the argument while calling the function `showForm("Invalid User Name or Password. Please Try Again");` , you should properly accept it in the function and handle it.

```
function showForm($formMessage){
echo $formMessage;
}
```

In your code `function showForm($formMessage='Invalid User Name And Password. Please Try Again.')` you are setting the default value for the argument in case no argument is passed. But where have you echoed the value of `$formMessage`?

The function I included above displays the message.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. Now, how to I redirect them back to the log in page? Or, better yet, change the error message to a pop  up rather than a new page?

Comment: OK, after researching this further I realize you cannot create a pop up window in PHP. You need to use JavaScript. But, instead of "echo $formMessage" could I replace that with "print 'alert("Invalid User Name or Password. Please Try Again")'; or are they one in the same? And if that print method works could I use the variables for the username and email address to show two separate alerts within the same function? Such as "print 'alert("The email address '. $_POST['email'].' is already registered")';" I have no clue as to how to imbed JavaScript into PHP using the code I presented.

Comment: You could use javascript inside PHP but using two consecutive alert messages is not a very good idea.
`echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert('Whatever you want to alert'); </script>";`

Answer (score -1):

For advanced error handling you can use try{} catch(){} construction (exceptions)